# Having trouble writing a structure to a binary file C++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, randomaccessfile, random-access

I'm trying to make a code that takes a structure, asks for user info and puts the data into a binary file called "output" so it can be read. I tried doing it with my code but it wasn't working. Can anybody help me fix it and tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here is my code that i am working on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h> 
using namespace std;

const int NAME_SIZE = 20;

struct Student{
    char fname[NAME_SIZE]; 
    int id; 

    };

int main() {
    int choice;
    fstream file; 
    Student person;

cout << "Populate the records of the file." << endl;
        file.open("output", ios::out | ios::binary);
        cout << "Populating the record with information."<< endl;      
        cout << "Enter the following data about a person " << endl;
        cout << "First Name: "<< endl;
        cin.getline(person.fname, NAME_SIZE);
        cout << "ID Number: "<< endl;
        cin >> person.id;
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person), sizeof(person));
        file.close();       
return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? Just saying 'it's not working' is very little help at all. Say exactly what goes wrong, and what you expected to happen instead. BTW your code looks fine to me, so it might be your expectations that are wrong, not the code.

Comment: when i tried to run the code, instead i got jumbled up text and symbols on the file

Comment: that's what binary output looks like.

Comment: The important thing is can you read back the same information from your file? That's the test whether it's worked or not.

Comment: @King The struct is POD, does not contain pointers, so you should be ok if you read back the file data.  Usually questions concerning binary file writing / reading are because the `struct` or `class` is not suitable for saving to binary files, but your `Student` struct is ok.

Comment: @john when i tried to read back my data it just read back more jumbled up mess. I used this try and read it back

Comment: @john      ifstream MyFile("output",ios::binary|ios::out);
  char ch;

  while(!MyFile.eof())
  {
  MyFile.get (ch);
  cout<<ch;
  }
  MyFile.close();
  }

Comment: That is not how you would read it back. You are trying to read it back as text. You wrote it as binary. You need to read similar to how you wrote.

Comment: @King Reading binary is very similar to writing binary `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person), sizeof(person));`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing between raw binary data and string data . You are writing filename which may have non printable characters after the name if the name is shorter than `NAME_SIZE` . Also `int id` is written as an integer which isn't printable .

This storage is valid if you want to store and load binary data like binary protocols .

If you want to store data as readable text you will have to serialize the data first but you won't be able to load them with simple `read`

Comment: how would i change it so that i'm not mixing data?

Answer (score 0):

the right way is to define a operator<< and operator>> for Student. Then it is a piece of cake dealing with saving and reading the structure.

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Student const & rhs)
{
   for(int i=0; i<NAME_SIZE; ++i)
   {
      os << rhs.fname[i];
   }
   os << id;
   return os;
}


std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Student & rhs)
{
   for(int i=0; i<NAME_SIZE; ++i)
   {
      is >> rhs.fname[i];
   }
   is >> id;
   return is;
}
```

So when you need to save to file you just do:

```
file << person;
```

when you need to read from it:

```
file >> person;
```

P.S.: I would suggest to make the operator implementations more robust than that, maybe through special markers, so that you can detect issues while reading from the file.